# Updating a SQL table through DataGrid in WPF - I cannot get the updated data from the datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a small program for checking things in and out.

The DB is in SQL Azure and I am using WPF and Linq to SQL.

The problem is that when I edit the DataGrid and tab all the way through to activate the RowEditEnding, the data that it grabs seems to be my old data, not my new data. It's just the oddest thing.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CreditCardTracker.CheckIn"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CreditCardTracker"
    xmlns:dblocal ="clr-namespace:CreditCardTracker.dbml"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Check In" Height="378.534" Width="707.978">


<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dg_cct" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="297" Width="683" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowEditEnding="dg_cct_RowEditEnding" Loaded="dg_cct_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CCT_PersonBorrowing}" Header="Borrower" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CCT_CardType}" Header="Card Type" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Check Out">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding CCT_CheckOutDateTime}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CCT_Vendor}" Header="Vendor" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CCT_Amount}" Header="Amount" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Check In">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding CCT_CheckInDateTime}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace CreditCardTracker
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for CheckIn.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CheckIn : Window
{

    public CheckIn()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(dg_cct_Loaded);
    }

    public void LoadTable()
    {
        dbml.creditCardTableDataContext dc = new dbml.creditCardTableDataContext();
        var q = from p in dc.CreditCardTrackers
                where p.CCT_CheckInDateTime == null
                select p;

        dg_cct.ItemsSource = q.ToList();
    }



    private void dg_cct_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
                dbml.creditCardTableDataContext context = new dbml.creditCardTableDataContext();
                dbml.CreditCardTracker borrowerRow = e.Row.DataContext as dbml.CreditCardTracker;
                int m = borrowerRow.Id;
                //MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());    

                var borrower = (from p in context.GetTable<dbml.CreditCardTracker>()
                                where p.Id == m
                                select p).SingleOrDefault();


                MessageBox.Show("Amount is " + borrowerRow.Id);

                borrower.CCT_Amount = borrowerRow.CCT_Amount;
                borrower.CCT_CardType = borrowerRow.CCT_CardType;
                borrower.CCT_CheckInDateTime = borrowerRow.CCT_CheckInDateTime;
                borrower.CCT_CheckOutDateTime = borrowerRow.CCT_CheckOutDateTime;
                borrower.CCT_PersonBorrowing = borrowerRow.CCT_PersonBorrowing;
                borrower.CCT_Vendor = borrowerRow.CCT_Vendor;
                context.SubmitChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated successfully.");
                LoadTable();
        }
    }

    private void dg_cct_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dbml.creditCardTableDataContext dc = new dbml.creditCardTableDataContext();
        var q = from p in dc.CreditCardTrackers
                where p.CCT_CheckInDateTime == null
                select p;

        dg_cct.ItemsSource = q.ToList();
    }
}
}
```

This bit of code:

```
dbml.CreditCardTracker borrowerRow = e.Row.DataContext as dbml.CreditCardTracker;
```

should give me the updated number (the number I typed into the DataGrid), but it gives me the old number instead. I can see it in the message box when I run:

```
MessageBox.Show("Amount is " + borrowerRow.Id);
```

It's really weird. I went through multiple tutorials, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh.. I figured it out.

I found it from this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c38fc695-d1ec-4252-87b7-feb484ee01e4/wpf-4-datagrid-roweditending?forum=wpf

The DataGrid control in WPF 4 is a little different with the DataGrid in WpfToolkit. By default, it updates the data after the selecting row changed, so we cannot get the new value in the RowEditEnding event .
We can solve this problem by setting the UpdateSourceTrigger of the binding, For example, we can set the  UpdateSourceTrigger as PropertyChanged so that wen can get the new value in the RowEditEnding event.

Something likes the follows:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowEditEnding="datagrid_RowEditEnding">
```